# How to make symmetric Low-Poly objects in meshmixer?

Tags: 3d-models, stl, meshmixer

I've made low-poly objects using Reduce function in Meshmixer. My objects are symmetric and I want to keep the symmetry in the low-poly because it's more beautiful, But the software doesn't necessary keep the symmetry.
using mirror function results in losing flat faces and many problems...
Is there any specific way to make a symmetric low-poly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to follow a four-step workflow:

1. Reduce complexity.
2. Cut the object along the symmetry plane.
3. Discard one half of the object.
4. Mirror the cut object along the cut symmetry plane.